# Is it possible to change the way Xcode imports files?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Here is my poor mans way of reusing code without hassle:

I have a `Commons` folder on the Mac where I store utility classes that I use in all my projects.

When I need a utility, I drag it from this `Commons` folder into Xcode as a *reference*. When I fix a bug in the utility or add new methods, it affects all apps.

Then I discovered that if the utility imports Foobar.h, and the project also has a `Foobar.h`, Xcode will load `Foobar.h` from the `Commons` folder instead of from the project as expected.

From my perspective when I have a file in my project and it imports `Foobar.h`, I would like to think Xcode looks for a `Foobar.h` within my project. But instead it magically finds the `Foobar.h` in the file system relative to where the file is located that imports `Foobar.h` - in this case it is the `Utility.h` in the `Commons` directory.

I realize Xcode offers other means to reuse code from different projects but I have found none of them intuitive enough. This approach with the `Commons` directory is so simple and works great if you are alone. Except for this one issue.

Can Xcode be configured so it always imports files in quotes relative to the project's own class files instead of relative to where the file (= the file that imports the other) is located in the file system?

Comment: Xcode does not do a good job when a workspace has multiple files of the same name in different paths. The only reasonable solution is for you to name things uniquely.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I think the core problem is telling Xcode that an import with double quotes should be relative to the project, not to the file. Then problem solved.

Comment: My statement is based on having a workspace that includes several projects, some of which have identically named files (such as AppController.m); attempting to open one a file by using the assistant editor with the .h or .xib in the primary editor opens the wrong one (the first one of that name it can find, consistently). I don't know what other same-name issues it has, but it's reasonable to think there are some.